# Storing ping error in batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Im working on a batch file that records the results of a ping.

Im using this code to store the values:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-9 delims==< " %%a IN ('PING -n 1 -w 2500 %IP%') DO IF 
"%%h"=="TTL" SET RESPONSE=%%g
```

But for some reason I can't get it to store any values when an ip does not ping (100% loss), all I get is echo is off.

I have even tried using ERRORLEVEL=1 and still nothing.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You say that an `echo is off` message is returned despite there being no `echo` command in your provided code. You also use `%IP%` despite it not being `Set` in your provided code. Try providing more code along with an example of your anticipated output.

Comment: "@"echo off
SET /P IP=enter ip.
:ping
"@"echo (PING -n 1 -w 2500 %IP%)>>ping.txt

FOR /F "tokens=1-9 delims==< " %%a IN ('PING -n 1 -w 2500 %IP%') DO IF "%%h"=="TTL" SET RESPONSE=%%a 

:Pingles
IF "RESPONSE"=="" (
set message= IT is down

) ELSE (

set message= IT is up

)

cls
echo. ==================================================================================
echo.
echo.          Current Ping:
echo           %RESPONSE%
echo.
echo.
echo    
echo    %message%       
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
Goto :ping

Comment: In order to bypass a line of your script you should use either a remark **`Rem`** or a comment marker **`::`** at it's beginning. Also, please add your code to your original question as an **edit**, it is almost undecipherable as a comment.

Comment: Additionally, taking a look at that code, you appear to be using `"@"echo` instead of `@echo` which could explain your 'echo is on' message.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when the `ping` does not connect, the `RESPONSE` variable is never set. Remove or comment out `@ECHO OFF` from the script in order to see what is actually happening.

```
C:\src>TYPE x.bat
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1-9 delims==< " %%a IN (`PING -n 1 -4 -w 2500 192.168.0.2`) DO (
    IF "%%h"=="TTL" (SET RESPONSE=%%g)
)
echo %RESPONSE%

C:\src>CALL x.bat

C:\src>FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1-9 delims==< " %a IN (`PING -n 1 -4 -w 2500 192.168.0.2`) DO (IF "%h" == "TTL" SET RESPONSE=%g )

C:\src>(IF "" == "TTL" SET RESPONSE=data: )

C:\src>(IF "" == "TTL" SET RESPONSE= )

C:\src>(IF "" == "TTL" SET RESPONSE= )

C:\src>(IF "(100%" == "TTL" SET RESPONSE=1 )

C:\src>echo
ECHO is on.
```

Comment: if the response variable is never set how would i create a statement to recognize this, i tried using if "Response" is null or ""

Comment: Have you tried `IF "%RESPONSE%" EQU "" {ECHO No response)`